# How to whitelist/blacklist parameters in @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to allow only `isActive` and `name` parameter in the @RequestBody and want to ignore `price` attribute.

Is there a way to do so in Spring Boot?

```
{
    "isActive": true,
    "name": "prandajsbdduts",
    "price": 10
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you just don't need to put `price` field in your DTO. When you have something like this:

```
public class SomeDTO {
    private Boolean isActive;
    private String name;
    /getters & setters
}
```

`price` will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the POJO to ignore unknown properties

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RequestResource {
    private Boolean isActive;
    private String name;
}
```